# How can I eliminate the margin at the top and bottom of a container

Tags: html, wordpress, css, underscores-wp

Am developing a WordPress site using the underscores theme and I just added a widget with contact info to my site  with the following code:

```
<div class="topheader">
   <div class="info">
      <?php if( is_active_sidebar( 'info' ) ) : ?>          
          <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'info' ); ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.topheader {
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
}
.info {
    max-width: 1280px;
}
```

The info is the first thing that I on the page. But I see that  there is a space at the top and at the bottom  where my slider is located.

How can I eliminate the existing margin that I see before and after the heading?

Cause at the moment I gap, then the widget, and after the widget there is another gap and only then the slider. 
I am tried to setting the header margin to 0px, but it didn't really work.

Here a screenshot
[image: Show a spacing at the top and at the bottom]

Comment: Can you paste here the URL of the working site..

Comment: @Naresh Kumar.P. Am developing on the localhost at the moment-http://localhost/scentology/

Comment: How can we help you, if we can't see what's going on?

Comment: I see that, that shows the margin. But it's obviously CSS, can you inspect and find out what margin is making it push away from the top? You know how to inspect elements right?

Comment: Just add the style for body and set margin to 0 `body{ margin:0px; }`

Comment: I think he's already done that

Comment: @Lee. Yes.I just targeted all the paragraph of class info(which is the content of the widget ) and added a margin   :0px. If fixed the top. The margin at the bottom remained.

Comment: there's probably something inside the widget that has bottom margin, that is extending the margin beyond the parent CSS

Comment: Check to that whether the `float:left;` property has been applied properly since if it is not applied sometimes the margin under the inside div will use the entire place.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I eliminate the existing margin that I see before and after the heading?

By heading do you mean an H3 tag by any chance? These are default in sidebars. You should just set `margin-top:0` on the H3 tags in your sidebars, to get rid of any margin pushing your sidebar down.

To counter act this, I would then add some `margin-bottom` to the widget block to space them out a bit.

I think that's what you mean.. but it's hard to understand without any visual representation of what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the start values in css like this:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Otherwise please copy the whole Code of the page here. Open it in your browser, open the site Code and copy all.

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the element and test whats causing the margin. You can try this code. This might help. But not sure because your question is not clear enough to know your code.

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.top-header, .info {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```